# Rstudio typeError undefined

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, miniconda

Whenever I try to launch Rstudio on Anaconda I get the following:

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'window.desktopHooks.notifyRCrashed')"

error. I clearly have no idea about what to do to start Rstudio

Comment: Have you installed `rstudio` in your conda environment?